# json log not collected by Wazuh manager

Tags: linux, wazuh

i have installed wazuh agent and manager. and i set the ip address of Manager in ossec.conf also i have configured in agent.conf the log type json and path

> /var/log/wildfly/app/app.json

but json logs not detected in wazuh manager alerts.json | .log

please any help from your side guys

Comment: have you tried `split`ting on `newline` the stdout. and printing it line by line ? Does the output really look like that ?

Comment: I see the problem. Change you loop to `for line in outp.split('\n'):..print(line)`. Note that i `split` the `outp` with `newline` and not `empty string`

Comment: also not working,

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the output line by line in the `data` array and then split each array element (i. e. line) into columns. To get this, replace

```
outp=stdout.read()
data=[outp]
```

with

```
data = stdout.readlines()
```